# Frame-rate drops when drawing 2D map tiles

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, frame-rate

**Update:** I figured out it has nothing to do with the camera but instead framerate drops when drawing my map tiles onto the screen.

[image: Framerate drops]

Here’s a link to a video showcasing the bug in action (For further reference): https://streamable.com/m4zuf3

Any and all guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Here's the draw functions:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        m_mainLevel.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

```
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            //Draw Background
            for (var i = 0; i < BackgroundTiles.Length; i++)
            {
                int id = BackgroundTiles[i].m_id;

                int column = id % TilesetTilesWide;
                int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)id / (double)TilesetTilesWide);

                int width = Map.TileWidth * 2;
                int height = Map.TileWidth * 2;

                float x = (i % Map.Width) * width;
                float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)Map.Width) * height;

                Rectangle tilesetRec = new Rectangle(TileWidth * column, TileHeight * row, TileWidth, TileHeight);
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, width, height);
                sb.Draw(Tileset, dest, tilesetRec, Color.White);
            }
        }
```

Is the problem that I'm drawing too many tiles per frame? the map size is 250 x 250 tiles, with each tile being 16x16px.

Comment: Sounds like judder. Don't forget to include the relevant code in your question so we can help you debug it.

Comment: For course, I figured out that it's not the camera but instead has to do with framerate drops.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
if(bounds.Intersects(dest)) sb.Draw(Tileset, dest, tilesetRec, Color.White);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate slightly on how this line of code solves the problem? As far as I can tell, it checks the coordinates of the tile it is about to draw and only draws it if it is onscreen, but I am unsure.